# Write the code to display a given plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

[image]

Write the code to display the exact image shown above.

Comment: Sounds like a give-me-the-codez question. And like homework.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way.

```
Show[
  Plot[{1/x}, {x, 0, 26},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, .6}}, 
    PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3]],
  Plot[{1/x}, {x, 2, 6},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, .6}},
    PlotStyle -> Transparent,
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> Red],
  Plot[1/x, {x, 8, 24},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, .6}},
    PlotStyle -> Transparent,
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> Blue],
  Ticks -> {{2, 6, 8, 24}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer:

```
Show[Plot[{1/x, If[2 <= x <= 6, 0, 1/x]}, {x, 0, 26}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FillingStyle -> {Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}, PlotStyle -> Black], 
 Plot[{1/x, If[8 <= x <= 24, 0, 1/x]}, {x, 0, 26}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FillingStyle -> {Blue},
   PlotStyle -> Black], Ticks -> {{2, 6, 8, 24}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: I don't think this produces the exact image requested.

Comment: Thanks, It actually works, goldbergs code for some reason does not display.

Comment: @vicsonsam, code by m_goldberg works fine, I edited small typo in there,